How can I scale a texture in relation to a plane's dimensions?
Might be a basic question, but I can't seem to figure out how to scale a texture based on the dimensions of a plane mesh.
My goal is to make a checkerboard plane as the ground, where every square is exactly 1 meter, regardless of how big I make the mesh. Essentially, I'm looking to figure out what I can attach to the "scale" input of the Checker Texture node to do that:

My initial thoughts were to try and get coordinate vectors for 2 of the corners, subtract those, take their magnitude and make that the scale, but I can't find a way to get those vectors.

Maybe just connect "Texture Coordinate: Generated" to "Checker Texture: Vector" ?

Do you want to scale the plane in Object Mode or Edit Mode? If in Edit Mode, use the Texture Coordinate > Object output to plug in the Vector input. Then the Scale of the Checker Texture should be set to 1 or 2, I don't remember yet and cannot test it right now. But it should be easy to find out, it is something obvious like 1 or 2 (or maybe 1/2 = 0.5?). But the object scale has to applied, i.e. be (1, 1, 1) in Object Mode.
